# Unable to send mail using mailx/mail from a host

Tags: email, unix, sendmail, mailx

On other hosts when I run something like:

```
echo 'foo' | mail -s 'bar' user
```

it sends the mail instantly and if i type `mailq` i am told it is empty. On this one host the mail command above runs but the mail is never received and if i type `mailq` i see stuff like:

```
5B9B340884     4140 Sat Sep  1 04:33:02  root@timber.com
(connect to mailrelay.timber.com[10.33.16.200]:25: Connection timed out)
```

What does that mean? I don't know what is failing and what would be needed to address this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that host you're sending it from can not connect to the mail relay, in your case `mailrelay.timber.com`, and is most likely either a firewall or some other networking issue.